# Upper bound of the function

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, inequality

[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408992/rearrange-the-inequalities) you can read my first question on this topic, namely:
$$\text{if    } f\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)-f\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)\le Ax+B\ln x-C, $$
where $f(x)$ is my function and $A$,$B$,$C$ are constants, then how to obtain:
$$ f(x)<\ldots ?$$
I managed to get a solution. Changing $\frac{x}{3}$ to $\frac{x}{4}$, $\frac{3x}{16}$, $\frac{9x}{64}$, $\frac{27x}{256}$, $\ldots$ (where $\frac{x}{4}=\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{x}{3}$, $\frac{3x}{16}=\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{x}{4}$ and so on), we obtain that:
$$ \begin{split}
\begin{aligned}
f\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)-f\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)&\le Ax+B\ln x-C \\
f\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)-f\left(\frac{3x}{16}\right)&\le A\frac{3x}{4}+B\ln\frac{3x}{4}-C \\
f\left(\frac{3x}{16}\right)-f\left(\frac{9x}{64}\right)&\le A\frac{9x}{16}+B\ln\frac{9x}{16}-C \\
f\left(\frac{9x}{64}\right)-f\left(\frac{27x}{256}\right)&\le A\frac{27x}{64}+B\ln \frac{27x}{64}-C \\
&\ldots
\end{aligned}
\end{split} $$
Note that after adding these all inequalities (assuming $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=0 $), only $ f(\frac{x}{3}) $ remains on the LHS. Moreover, the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^k$ is convergent and it can be easily computed that:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^k=4 $$
Therefore:
$$ f\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\le4Ax+B\ln 4x-C$$ 
and:
$$ f\left(x\right)\le12Ax+B\ln 12x-C$$ 
I would be very interested if this approach is valid and in any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote $\psi$ for $f$ which is just  a typo. BUT the sum of the LHS is not valid if you  don't assume that $$ \lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=0 .$$  But the RHS sum is wrong. We have  $$\ln ((3/4)^nx)= \ln x +n \ln (3/4)$$  so $$\sum _{n=0}^{n=m} (B \ln ((3/4)^n.x)-C=Bm \ln x +B((m^2+m)/2) \ln (3/4) -mC$$ which goes to $\infty$ or to $- \infty$ as $m \to \infty$ ,unless $B=C=0$.

Comment: I don't understand your point about the RHS. How do you get $\sum _{n=0}^{n=m} (B \ln ((3/4)^n.x)-C$...? Can't I just add all these inequalities?